# Handle Async postback from gridview content control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, asynchronous

I have a gridview within an update pannel. The gridview contains controls that need to throw async postbacks. I have them registered with the scriptmanager during row bind, but I don't see their change event getting handled by anything. The gridview's rowcommand event doesn't fire. Where should I catch these postbacks?

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually specify Async and Full Postback triggers .

[In this article](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Assign-PostBack-Trigger-Full-PostBack-for-LinkButton-inside-GridView-within-AJAX-UpdatePanel-in-ASPNet.aspx) explains how to set AJAX UpdatePanel Triggers i.e. PostBackTrigger or AsyncPostBackTrigger for Button or LinkButton placed in GridView within AJAX UpdatePanel.

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You should wire up the event handlers just like you would if you wanted full postbacks. The fact they are partial doesn't change how the event fires from that perspective.

If the events aren't firing, then the triggering mode of the update panel may be set incorrectly.